# Extracting name between two delimiters via awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a string like this

```
<user>@<server>:<port>:/foo/bar
```

and I would like to extract the user, server, port and directory.

The user can easily be extracted by

```
echo <string> | awk -F"@" '{print $1;}'
```

But the server lies within two different delimeters. Is this possible via `awk`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can combine two [`cut`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)) commands to extract the server name:

```
echo <string> | cut -d":" -f1 | cut -d"@" -f2
```

Explanation:

- `echo <string> |` use the string as input
- `cut -d":" -f1 |` set field delimiter to `:` and extract the first field (`<user>@<server>`)
- `cut -d"@" -f2` set filed delimiter to `@` and extract the secon field (`<server>`)

Comment: A brief explanation of the arguments used would be awesome in the answer.

Comment: @edigu thanks for the note. I edited my answer

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible - using a regular expression for the delimiter

```
$ echo '<user>@<server>:<port>:/foo/bar' | awk -F'@|:' '{print $1; print $2; print $3;print $4;}'
<user>
<server>
<port>
/foo/bar
```

or

```
$ echo '<user>@<server>:<port>:/foo/bar' | awk -F'[@:]' '{print $1; print $2; print $3;print $4;}'
<user>
<server>
<port>
/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 2):

How about [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) only,

```
grep -Eoi "[a-z/]{1,}"  <<< "<user>@<server>:<port>:/foo/bar"
user
Server
port
/foo/bar
```